# Show image randomly when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, random, imagebutton

I made 9 `imagebuttons` and 1 `button`.

I want only 4 buttons shows images when button is clicked, and it shows randomly every time button is pressed, how will that be possible?

Comment: what ever you are doing use, random function of Math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  // add your image buttons to this list
        ArrayList<ImageButton> allImageButtons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
        allImageButtons.add(imgbtn1); //etc... for all 8 image buttons
```

Then in your button click method

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (randomNumbers.size() < 4)
        {
            int num = rnd.nextInt(9);
            if (!randomNumbers.contains(num))
                randomNumbers.add(num);
        }

        for (int i=0;i<allImageButtons.size();i++)
        {
            if (randomNumbers.contains(i))
                allImageButtons.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                allImageButtons.get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array that include image's src name and you can use

```
string imageArray = Name of yur images
int random = (int )(Math.random() * 9);
```

Then you can chance your image button images according to this random number.

```
imgButton.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[random]);
```

I hope it is clear and helpful.